# Visual Studio Code opens unwanted C# file

Tags: c#, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I searched for some time now but couldn'd find anything that helped. Whenever I open a project in Visual Studio Code, it opens a second editor window with a c#-File of a unity-projekt I started. Even as I deleted the file and even the containing folder, it still opens the file.

I tried to supress it with

```
"window.restoreWindows": "none"
```

it still will open the file every time. My question is how I can clean up Visual-Studio-Code in such a way I can use it normally.

I use Kubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS13C, if that should matter. I used Unity-Engine once with VSC but haven't it installed anymore.

Comment: What are the extensions you installed? Remove those Unity related ones and this issue might disappear.

Comment: Uninstalled everything, removed unnecissary extensions. The only ones remaining are Docker-Plugin, AsciiDoc-Live Preview, MS-German language Pack and vscode-pdf. The error still remains.